# how to plot a graph with some offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, offset

How to plot a graph with some offset in matplotlib?

I have plotted a graph and I want to plot another graph with same x-axis and Y-axis but with some offset from the first plotted graph(or even base x-axis as reference). I don't want to use subplots option.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: why don't you add an offset to your data?

Comment: `plt.plot(x, y + offset)`

Comment: I am plotting two arrays, when I tried to do plt.plot (x, y + offset), it says the error as TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list. how can I do that @JulienSpronck

Comment: that's because you cannot add a number to a list ... but if you first transform your list to a numpy array, then you can

Answer (score 2):

Just add an offset to your data. If you use lists, you can convert them to numpy array first before adding the offset.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [10, 13, 11]
y = np.array(y)    

offset = 5

plt.plot(x, y+offset)
plt.show()
```