# Move a plot along x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

[image]

I have the graph shown above, one in blue and one in orange colour, generated using matplotlib. I want to move the orange graph to the left so as to align it with the blue graph. How can I do that ?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the data and code to plot?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried using offset as mentioned in one of the comment. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

By adding an offset to the data of the orange graph. In your case you would substract the desired offset from the x-values.

Similar to [how to plot a graph with some offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309539/how-to-plot-a-graph-with-some-offset)